# Ganymed ssh2 : how to solve (y/n) prompt in command line 

Tags: java, ssh

I'm using Ganymede ssh2 to connect to server from my Java app and do some work there.
It works perfectly but problems are ssh commands that request approval, eg.
a command

```
stop someService
```

returns

```
Are you sure (y/n)?
```

and after appropriate key stroke (y/n) it moves on.

Currently I'm using implementation given by ssh2 ganymed example, smth like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;

public class ConnectUtil(String hostname, String username, String password, String command)
{

    try
    {
        Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
        conn.connect();

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (isAuthenticated == false)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

        sess.execCommand(command);

        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true)
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        sess.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }       
}
```

After calling this util class with above mentioned command('stop someService'), it gets stucked at

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

and everything breaks after server timeout.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue are more than welcome.

Thanks a lot,
Milos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Session` has a `getStdin()` method, you should write the response to the question to that.

Either that or find out if the command that's demanding input has a 'non-interactive' mode that won't prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no mode for this command that doesn't prompt. However, there is a 'getStdin()' in 'Session' object. I tried to use it but can't figure out how to use it. This is code I added: '   Session sess = conn.openSession();

   sess.execCommand(command);
   
   sess.getStdin().write("pwd".getBytes());
   
   InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
   
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));' There is something wrong but don't know what?!

Comment: Sorry, the code I added is:  `Session sess = conn.openSession();

   sess.execCommand(command);
   
   sess.getStdin().write("y".getBytes());
   
   InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
   
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));`

Comment: wrap the stdin stream in a writer then write "y\n", so that it sends carriage return

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sending "y" with carriage return "\n" did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use stdin instead of exec then you have to do session.startShell() first. Read the FAQs.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code...

```
sess.executeCommand("ena"+'\n' +"pass"+'\n' +"exit"+'\n');
```